# How many satisfying assignments are there in a set of 3-CNF clauses where no clause share the same variable?

Tags: math, sat

Maybe a little outside the scope of this site, but I figured enough people here would know this so that I am giving it a shot.

Say I have a set of 3-CNF clauses

```
 S = {Clause1, Clause2} = {<x1 or x2 or not x3>, <x4 or x5 or x6>}
```

Each variable range over `{0,1}`

How many satisfying assignments are there for S? In general, how many satisfying assignments are there for S is the size of S is k?

This is a question about what is a satisfying assignment for 3-disjunctive clause as much as it is about counting. For example when I just have [image: C = x_1 or x_2 or (not x_3)], there are 2<sup>3</sup> = 8 possible assignments:

```
(111),(011),(101),(110),(100),(010),(001),(000)
```

But which one of these are satisfying assignments?

Comment: You might want to use images instead of latex, since that doesn't work on this site. You can use chart.googlesapis : https:// chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=<latex text here>

Comment: thanks for the tip! however I cannot get it to work?

Comment: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=C%3Dx_1%5Cvee%20x_2%5Cvee%20%5Cbar%7Bx_3%7D -- then save it to your computer and upload it if it doesn't work directly from the web

Answer (score 1):

For clauses that do not share any variables, the counting is pretty trivial.

For each set of variables satisfying the first clause, you can pick any set of variables satisfying the second clause. Thus you simply want the product of satisfying assignments of each of your clauses.

[image: product]

Comment: @chibro2 Does this answer your question ? Or do you need any complement ?